# How to return image URL from web api C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm facing problem in returning image URL from a web api in C#

I have the following code:

```
  Product[] _products = new Product[]
   {


        new Product { Id = 1, Name = "AC Split 12K Inverter", Price = "20997 SDG",Image=@"\\192.168.2.113\C$\abc.png" },
        new Product { Id = 2, Name = "AC Split 18K Inverter", Price = "31200 SDG",Image=@"\\192.168.2.113\C$\abz.png" },
        new Product { Id = 3, Name = "AC Split 24K Inverter", Price = "40000 SDG",Image=@"\\192.168.2.113\C$\aby.png" }
   };

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {

        return _products;
    }
```

but i got the following response

> [{"Id":1,"Name":"AC Split 12K Inverter","Price":"20997 SDG","Image":"\\\\192.168.2.113\\C$\\abc.png"},{"Id":2,"Name":"AC Split 18K Inverter","Price":"31200 SDG","Image":"\\\\192.168.2.113\\C$\\abz.png"},{"Id":3,"Name":"AC Split 24K Inverter","Price":"40000 SDG","Image":"\\\\192.168.2.113\\C$\\aby.png"}]

and i'm consuming the json response from android device using the following code but the image URL i got double \ in it

```
try {
           // JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
          //  JSONArray jsonArray =  jsonObject.getJSONArray("");
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(content);
            for(int i =0;i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject productObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                arrayList.add(new Products(
                     // productObject.getInt("id"),
                        productObject.getString("Name"),
                        productObject.getString("Price"),
                        productObject.getString("Image")

                ));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you tell us what response you *expected* to get, and why? The JSON you've shown looks fine for the values you're providing. If you need to turn `@"\\192.168.2.113\C$\abc.png"` into a URL, you'll need to set the `Image` property to that URL after performing whatever mapping is appropriate.

Comment: Seem okay to me.

Comment: i want reply like "\\192.168.2.113\C$\abc.png" but i got double \\

Comment: i'm consuming the response from android device

Answer (score 0):

When a string is prefixed with an @ it is a literal string and escape characters are no longer used. You can still escape a double quote by using "" like this "my "" string". This will be interpreted as: my " string.

The JSON however needs to escape the backslash, and that is also what the string would look like in C# without the @.

Your Android device should read it correctly if you are using a JSON deserializer.

Comment: please check my android code i edited the question and added it there

Comment: If you hover over it in a debugger to view the value, the IDE is probably showing it to you as an escaped string. Write the value to console and it should be correct.